# AuthenticationError with Quandl API

Tags: python, quandl

I'm getting

```
AuthenticationError: (Status 400) (Quandl Error QEAx01) We could not recognize your API key. Please check your API key and try again
```

```
import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'PDWYXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
```

After creating the account I got this API Key and after using this in the code it is not recognised. What else needs to be done to make it work.

Comment: 1) I hope this is not your actual API key as those should not be shared, and 2) this sounds like it may be a better question for Quandl as to why they key they gave you doesn't work

Comment: Yes I altered the API Key Don't Worry. I was missing a character in the API Key that's why I was getting the other. Thank you anyway